# Where does shubhasya sheeghRam come from?

Tags: source

I have heard it is from the Ramayana, specifically Ravana's deathbed advice to Lakshmana. But it appears, from the answer to an HSE question on what Ravana told Lakshmana, that the Valmiki Ramayana says Ravana died immediately. So where is it really from?